# Update query C# SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

On clicking the EditAll button an exception is thrown.

```
private void editAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\DELL\source\repos\phoneBookwin\phoneBookwin\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();

            string value;
            bool friendCheck = newFriends.Checked;
            bool familyCheck = newFamily.Checked;
            bool emergencyCheck = newEmergency.Checked;
            bool collCheck = newColl.Checked;
            if (friendCheck)
                value = newFriends.Text;
            else if (familyCheck)
                value = newFamily.Text;
            else if (emergencyCheck)
                value = newEmergency.Text;
            else if (collCheck)
                value = newColl.Text;
            else
                value = "";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Contacts set Name='"+newName.Text+"' Contacts='"+newNumber.Text+"' Email='"+newEmail.Text+"' Group='"+value+"' where Name='"+changeName.Text+"')", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.Hide();
            Form1 save = new Form1();
            save.ShowDialog();
            con.Close();
        }
```

The exception thrown is

> Incorrect Syntax near Contacts

Comment: Your sql is missing some commas to make it valid. Concatenating sql like that makes it vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: You need commas between the columns you're setting

Comment: **what** exception (what is the message? what is the exception type?) is thrown, and on **what line exactly**?

Comment: Have a look at proper SQL syntax, try to execute your queries directly on your server, and check the documentation for queries parameters (never trust user input!)

Comment: You have already been told to parameterize your sql statements from previous questions. Please take the time to learn to write code properly.

Comment: @Crowcoder It say 'incorrect syntax near update' after adding comma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SQL looks to be invalid, however; that's probably a good thing, because right now this is a massive security hole - you *must* use parameters with SQL, otherwise with your string-concatenation approach you're going to have problems including:

- security, see "SQL injection"
- correctness, see names like "Peter O'Toole"
- correctness, with formatting in different client locales (especially dates and numbers)
- server performance (query plan cache)

Parameter code is tedious, but tools like "Dapper" make it painless:

```cs
// see "using" here - we need to Dispose connections!
using var con = new SqlConnection(...);
// ...
// (the following is an extension method added by Dapper)
con.Execute(@"
update Contacts
set    Name = @newName, Contacts = @newNumber,
       Email = @newEmail, Group = @newGroup
where  Name = @changeName", new {
    newName = newName.Text,
    newNumber = newNumber.Text,
    newEmail = newEmail.Text,
    newGroup = value,
    changeName = changeName.Text
});
```

Also note that names are not unique and should not be used (by themselves) as predicates.